# LibreOffice Calc - Points on XY graph (multiple Y values for one X!)

Tags: libreoffice

How can I create such a graph in libreoffice calc?

[image]

I tried to do it but my efforts are fruitless. If I have this table for example

```
+-----+-----+
| 12  | 109 |
+-----+-----+
| 12  | 5   |
+-----+-----+
| 54  | 41  |
+-----+-----+
| 108 | 15  |
+-----+-----+
```

The program will show me two 12's on the x-axis, which i want to avoid. This should create only one 12 on the axis and then two values on the Y-axis (109 and 5 respectively)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the X/Y (Scatter) chart type:

[image]